# CDATA not working for C++ code inside a <pre> tag

Tags: html, xml, cdata, pre

I have a problem with outputting some C++ inside a `pre` tag.

The XHTML code I have is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>   
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml" />
   </head>
   <body>
   <pre><![CDATA[
   #include <cstdio> 

   int x = 1;
   ]]></pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

But when I try to view the webpage I only see

```
int x = 1;
]]>
```

and not

```
#include <cstdio> 

int x = 1;
```

as I want to.

What don't I understand about `CDATA` behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDATA is not an HTML construct; it is an XML (and XHTML) construct.

Comment: Should I use something else than `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the webpage ? Can a browser understand the XHTML code I want to use ?

Comment: Let's get one thing sorted first: are you writing HTML, or XHTML? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: I honestly never really asked myself the question. By looking at the differences between the two, the code respect XHTML constraints (tags properly nested, closed, lowercase..)

Comment: That doesn't mean that it isn't HTML. The key issue here is, is that if you are writing XHTML (and sending your page as application/xhtml+xml, which you should always do with XHTML), you can use the CDATA construct. There is no such feature in HTML, so you'll have to use entities.

Comment: I've edited the question will a full example with `application/xhtml+xml` that is still not working as I would like. Sorry for the confusion between HTML and XHTML.

Comment: A very common misconception is that the `meta` tag for setting `Content-type` works at all. It doesn't work at all. Make sure your file's name ends in `.xhtml` and try again.

Comment: @DelanAzabani let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2771/discussion-between-loic-fevrier-and-delan-azabani)